# why i get different value width window using react js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, resize

example:
[resize using react js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n4fF4.gif)

this is my code:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

const getWidthWindow = () => {
  const [widthWindow, setWidthWindow] = useState(null)
  
  const updateDimensions = () => {
    setWidthWindow(window.screen.width)
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(widthWindow)

    setWidthWindow(window.screen.width)
    updateDimensions()
    window.addEventListener('resize', updateDimensions)
    return () => window.removeEventListener('resize', updateDimensions)
  }, [widthWindow])
}

export default getWidthWindow;
```

I want to get the window width value but the result is like it doesn't match the window size so how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Your code is correct but the logging isn't.

Add a hook to log the dimensions when it updates:

```js
useEffect(() => {
   console.log(windowDimensions)
}, [windowDimensions])
```

[Working codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/gifted-wildflower-fri82?file=/src/App.js&resolutionWidth=605&resolutionHeight=675).

Comment: I tried to make it like this and tried to add your suggestion to this: https://codesandbox.io/s/broken-darkness-6iyoi?file=/src/getWidthWindow.jsx:0-516
but still not like that

Comment: Oops, I forgot to fork the Sandbox. I've updated the link.

Answer (score 0):

I go with the above answer of adding **windowDimensions** to the useEffect's Dependency array but I like to add up little sugar on top of it..

On Resize, the event gets triggered continuously and impacts performance a bit..
So, I have implemented throttling to improve the performance..

> Answer for your updated question: [Stackblitz link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-omrw3q?file=src%2FResizer.js)

```
const GetWidthWindow = () => {
  const [widthWindow, setWidthWindow] = useState(window.innerWidth);

  useEffect(() => {
    let throttleResizeTimer = null;
    function handleResize() {
      clearTimeout(throttleResizeTimer);
      throttleResizeTimer = setTimeout(
        () => setWidthWindow(window.innerWidth),
        500
      );
    }

    window.addEventListener('resize', handleResize);
    return () => window.removeEventListener('resize', handleResize);
  }, [widthWindow]);

  return <p>{JSON.stringify(widthWindow)}</p>;
};

export default GetWidthWindow;
```

> Answer for your old question:

```
useEffect(() => {
// implement throttle for little performance gain
let throttleResizeTimer = null;
function handleResize() {
  clearTimeout(throttleResizeTimer);
  throttleResizeTimer = setTimeout(
    () => setWindowDimensions(getWindowDimensions()),
    500
  );
}

window.addEventListener('resize', handleResize);
return () => window.removeEventListener('resize', handleResize);  }, [windowDimensions]);
```